# Error: No implicit view available for String => org.apache.lucene.document.Document

Tags: apache-spark, lucene

I am trying to use Spark LuceneRDD with Record Linkage concept from the  [link](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd/wiki/Record-Linkage).

I did all the steps mentioned in the link but I am getting the error

> Error: No implicit view available for String => org.apache.lucene.document.Document

I tried by adding lucene jar for spark shell but I am still getting the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please the show you have actually created, not just what is in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Lucene jars will not help you here. The problem is, that some functionality is using **implicit** features of Scala. What it means, it should be some mapping function that will transform String into Lucene document.

When I looked over github, I found one implicit thing that will do the conversion - https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/zouzias/spark/lucenerdd/package.scala

So, you just need to add import to your code, something like this:

```
import org.zouzias.spark.lucenerdd._
```

or even more precisely, if you just need only 1 conversation (could be not your case however)

```
import org.zouzias.spark.lucenerdd.stringToDocument
```